# How to enter different data types through input redirection?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, io-redirection

Im having a little bit of trouble wrapping my head around input redirection in C. I am making a minesweeper program that takes in a mine sweeper field and calculates how many bombs are around each square. Just like in the game.

Here is an example:

a * = bomb
a . = safe space

```
* . . .
. . * .
. . . .
```

would come out of the program like this:

```
* 2 1 1
1 2 * 1
0 1 1 1
```

So. On to the problem

I am trying to have my program get input from the command prompt Ex:

```
./a.out < someFile.txt
```

but I can't quite figure out how to properly read from this file.
The file will look something like this:

```
10 10
*.*.*.*.*.
.*.*.*.*.*
*.*.*.*.*.
.*.*.*.*.*
**********
.*.*.*.*.*
**********
.*.*.*.*.*
*.*.*.*.*.
.*.*.*.*.*
```

the first line consists of two integers denoting the size of the grid coming after.
Then following that, the grid and all its pieces come in. So how would i properly input these numbers/ chars from file. Here is what i have.

```
    int i;
int j;
int xSize;
int ySize;
char tempChar;




xSize = fgetc(stdin); 

ySize = fgetc(stdin);    


for (i = 0; i < ySize; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < xSize; j++){

           tempChar = fgetc(stdin); 
           if(tempChar != '\n'){           // make sure it's not a newline char
           gridArray[j][i] = tempChar;// grid array is an array of chars 
        }
    }
}
```

The program will only read in 1 and 0 as the input for the first line, instead of 10 10. and the rest is all jumbled up and in the wrong place. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem...

```
xSize = fgetc(stdin); // Returns 1. The stream is now "0 10....."
ySize = fgetc(stdin); // Returns 0. The stream is now " 10....."
```

You can use `fscanf` to read the numbers and skip everything after that till the end of the line.

```
fscanf("%d %d %[^\n]*", &xSize, &ySize);
              // Format specifier for skipping until '\n'
```

Now read the `'\n'` and discard it.

```
fgetc();
```

Comment: so the fscanf is taking in the two integers there and the newline character?

Comment: because It is giving me a segmentation fault whenever i run this. Not sure if that is because it isn't reading from the file or not

Comment: If you can post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the problem might be easy to detect. With the posted code, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do what do expect using `fscanf` also..

Try with following code

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    main()
    {

    FILE *fp;
    int i,j;
    int a,b;
    char array[20][20],ch;
    fp=fopen("file.txt","r");
    fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&a,&b);
    printf("a=%d b=%d\n",a,b);
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
    for(j=0;j<b;j++){
    fscanf(fp,"%c",&ch);
    if(ch!='\n'){
    array[i][j]=ch;
    }
    else{
    --j;
    }
    }
    }

    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
    for(j=0;j<b;j++){
    printf("%c ",array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
    }
```

My file `file.txt` having content like

```
   3 10
   asdfggfdsa
   zxcvbmnbvc
   abcdefghij
```

For checking purpose only , i am keeping letters. You can keep `*` /`.` whatever you want character.

output is

```
      :~$ ./a.out 
      a=3 b=10
      a s d f g g f d s a 
      z x c v b m n b v c 
      a b c d e f g h i j 
      :~$
```

(In `printf` function i have given space thats why space is present between letters)